# Running a Bazel executable target as a Bazel test?

Tags: bazel

I have a Bazel executable target (of type `fsharp_binary`, but I don't *think* it should matter) that I can run using `bazel run`.

```sh
bazel run //my_app.exe
```

I would like to use this executable as a test, so that when I call `bazel test` it gets built and executed, and a non-zero exit code is considered a test failure.

```sh
bazel test //...
```

What I am looking for is something like this:

```py
test_of_executable(
  name = "my_test",
  executable = "//my_app.exe",
  success_codes = [ 0 ],
)
```

Then:

```sh
bazel test //:my_test
```

How can I achieve this in Bazel?

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap your app as a `sh_test`. See for example https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/1969.

What I use in my codebase is:

**BUILD.bazel**:

```
sh_test(
    name = "test",
    srcs = ["test.sh"],
    data = [
        "//:some_binary",
    ],
)
```

**test.sh**

```
some_project/some_subdir/some_binary
```

See [here](https://github.com/Vertexwahn/FlatlandRT/blob/master/devertexwahn/flatland/tests/acceptance_tests/BUILD.bazel) for an real example.

Comment: Is it possible to generate `test.sh` automatically so that I don't need to maintain the path to the binary?

Comment: yes you can use a genrule https://bazel.build/reference/be/general#genrule